# array gets wiped out

Tags: c, arrays

I have a situation where I am writing commands to a command buffer. When it is time for a command in the command buffer to be executed, the command is processed and sent out the UART to another subsystem. When the command is processed, the data that needs to be sent out the UART is stored in a queue and a flag is raised. Then shortly after my main while loop checks to see if the flag has been raised, and if so, sends the data out the UART. However, between the time the command is processed, and the time it is ready to send out the UART, the array gets corrupted. I know this because I am using an in-circuit debugger and setting breakpoints. What in the world is going on, and how do I fix this?

This is an example of what happens:

Right after processing and storing in queue (`a[]` is the queue):

```
a[0] = 0x3;
a[1] = 0x6;
a[2] = 0x9;
```

Right before it is ready to be sent out UART:

```
a[0] = 0x3;
a[1] = 0x6;
a[2] = 0x0;
```

or sometimes even,

```
a[0] = 0x3;
a[1] = 0x0;
a[2] = 0x0;
```

Behavior is random. Sometimes only one byte gets corrupted, and other times, two bytes.

Comment: programming lang?  code samples? etc.

Comment: Without more info, the bug could be literally anything.  Are you sure `a` is safely allocated?  Are you sure everything else is safely allocated?  (e.g. Are all your other pointer values correct?)  Are there any weird interrupts that are jumping in and breaking things?

Comment: Check out valgrind - Its very useful for debugging memory errors like this.

Comment: I have two timer interrupts. One is an external interrupt at a very accurate 1Hz, the other is a timer interrupt every 1ms. When the external interrupt is disconnected, there is no issue, and the command array does not get wiped out. When it is connected, then the array is wiped out sometimes.

Comment: when i say more code, i mean relevant bits that access the array.. not just the array assignments.  You now talk about having interrupts - does code get triggered on interrupt?  If so, what?  Also, how are you allocating the memory for this array?  This could be a bug in your platform's allocator or perhaps you are using memory that you shouldn't be using.

Comment: Two segments of code that deal with the array. When the internal timer interrupt has incremented a variable to 99ms, the array is filled with the command. Then the the external interrupt interrupts, and 499ms after this interrupt, the array is read. When the array is read right after it is written to, the array contains the correct values. After it is read 499ms after the external interrupt, the array values are corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Set a watch on the bytes. That way, the debugger will stop when anyone writes to them.

Comment: Programming language is C, using MPLAB IDE, with an ICD2, and Microchip PIC24FJGA110

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a memory scribble. Something else out there is unexpectedly accessing your array's memory. This could be due to pointers to freed memory not being set to NULL or possibly some hardware writing to the same memory. Impossible to say without more info.